# Binding to a property in another namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a style setter in a themes xaml file. I'm trying to bind the value of the Setter to a bool peoperty in a view model.

I've got the namespace to the view model in themes:

```
 xmlns:propertyGrid="clr-namespace:MY.App.Controls.PropertyGrid;assembly=MY.APP.Controls"
```

and the binding in the style:

```
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource propertyGrid:PropertyGridViewModel}, Path=AreCategoriesAutoExpanded}"/>
```

Finally in the viewmodel I just have an auto property:

```
public bool AreCategoriesAutoExpanded { get; set; }
```

However I get an exception at run time:

```
Cannot find resource named 'propertyGrid:PropertyGridViewModel'. Resource names are case sensitive
```

If I try to use a dynamic resource resource it compains that I can only bind to a dp. What is wrong with this binding? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Check the capitalization of your assembly name and namespace, are those correct? In the namespace its App, and your assembly its APP. Maybe it's just something stupid like that.

Also, remove the StaticResource part, and just use {Binding propertyGrid:PropertyGridViewModel}

Comment: Is `PropertyGridViewModel` a static class? I think since you're using `StaticResource`, it will look for a public static class of that name containing a public static property of `AreCategoriesAutoExpanded`

Comment: put your class "PropertyGridViewModel" code

Comment: You need to declare your viewModel in the way like '<propertyGrid:PropertyGridViewModel x:Key='viewModel'/> before using it. And then you could reference it as 'Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"'. But in this way, you lose the control of your viewmodel object, which means that it is difficult for you to get the object reference.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if your ViewModel is a static class with a static property, like this:

```
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static propertyGrid:PropertyGridViewModel.AreCategoriesAutoExpanded}"/>
```

You were missing the 'x:Static' bit, which should fix it.