# Binding from Attached Property to Attached Property

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a situation where I need to add binding like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:key="bla">
    <views:MyView props:special.MyAttachProperty="{Binding props:special.MyAttachProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

So the same attache property value will be both,

and change according to changes on the data in the viewmodel.

But this binding fails at run time:

> [0:] Binding: 'props:special' property not found on '(my data)', target property: 'views:MyView.MyAttachProperty'

How do I make this work?

Comment: Maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/q/35346603/5228202 please provide some more details. A guess try with `Binding Source="{x:Static props:special}" Path="MyAttachProperty"`

Comment: I will check it today

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: Could you provide an update please ?

Comment: Eventually I used a Behavior to place the value on the member inside the DataTemplate.

Comment: You can share your solution it would be helpful for future visitors